# Log Analytics Workspace / Azure Watchlist: KQL Filtering on datetime

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

I'm having trouble converting a date value in a watchlist to be understood as a datetime value.

I've tried using format_datime(), datetime(), date() but the value becomes blank.

steps to reproduce:

1. create a watchlist with a column that has a date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`
2. run a query where you attempt to filter on the date column. (ensure the date value meets the condition)

```
let examplewatchlist = _GetWatchlist("exampleWatchlist");
examplewatchlist
| where ReviewDate > now() // now is 01/03/2024
```

For example, here is my watchlist (a total of 1 row)
[image]

My desired output for the above query should be this one row in the watchlist because it satisfies ReviewDate > now()

Comment: Can you provide your watchlist table with dates before converting and your expected output too

Comment: Can you provide it in text format and expected output too

Comment: @RithwikBojja I've provided my example watchlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a watchlist same as you have :

[image]

You can use below **`KQL query`** to get expected results:

```
let examplewatchlist = _GetWatchlist("test1");
examplewatchlist
| extend test = split(ReviewDate, "/")
| extend ReviewDate2 = make_datetime(toint(test[2]),toint(test[1]),toint(test[0]))
| where ReviewDate2 >  now() + 17d
```

[image]

ReviewDate is not stored as datetime, it needs to transformed as above.

To test date with now():

[image]

Later you can use `|project-away  test` to remove extra columns.